# Simple latitude/longitude + integer database?

Tags: database, geospatial, key-value-store

Is there a fast, persistent database for storing a **latitude, longitude, and integer** value for quick geo-spacial lookups?

The idea is that I have lots of ID's of different things and I want to search by lat/lon squares for all the ID's in a given location.

My first thought was the creative use of key-value store like membase or redis. However, I can't figure out a method to search based on properties like latitude and longitude short of creating set sized lat/lon blocks and placing all ids as the value (which doesn't work very well).

Answer (score 5):

How about Spatiallite, geocouch, mongodb with the spatial extension, or postgis? Don't use MySQL - it doesn't have most of the spatial functions currently implemented

Comment: I wasn't aware of Spatiallite - knowing how light SQLite is that sounds like a neat project to test. The problem with GeoCouch, MongoDB, and PostGIS is that they are much more than just a simple lat/lon store. Each one takes many megabytes of memory just to load the system - and isn't optimized for large data sets of small values like three floating point numbers. However, PostGIS or an in-memory Spatiallite seem to be the best mainstream options I've found so far.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for MongoDB. Its simple and has good support for Geospatial indexing and neighborhood queries.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing#GeospatialIndexing-Querying